# Não chega e-mail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, envio-de-email

Estou tentando montar um código para envio de e-mail em minha página. Não ocorre nenhum erro, mas eu também não recebo o e-mail. Alguém saberia me dizer por que?

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub btnEnviar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnviar.Click
    Dim Mensagem As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    Dim Email As New SmtpClient()
    Dim basicAuthenticationInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("midiassociais@jnmoura.com.br", "password", "smtp.jnmoura.com.br")

    Email.Host = "smtp.jnmoura.com.br"
    Email.Port = 587
    Email.EnableSsl = False
    Email.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    Email.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo
    Email.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

    Mensagem.From = New MailAddress("midiassociais@jnmoura.com.br")
    Mensagem.To.Add(New MailAddress("rodrigocichetto@gmail.com"))
    Mensagem.To.Add("rodrigocichetto@gmail.com") 

    Mensagem.Subject = "Teste de envio de email"
    Mensagem.Body = "TESTE"

    Mensagem.IsBodyHtml = False
    Mensagem.Priority = MailPriority.High

    Email.Send(Mensagem)

End Sub
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network
         host="smtp.jnmoura.com.br"
         port="587"
         userName="midiassociais@jnmoura.com.br"
         password="password"
         enableSsl="true"
    />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com o seguinte código

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub btnEnviar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnviar.Click
    Dim Mensagem As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    Dim Email As New SmtpClient()

    Email.Host = "smtp.jnmoura.com.br"
    Email.Port = 587

    Mensagem.From = New MailAddress("midiassociais@jnmoura.com.br")
    Mensagem.To.Add(New MailAddress("rodrigocichetto@gmail.com"))

    Mensagem.Subject = "Teste de envio de email"
    Mensagem.Body = "TESTE"

    Mensagem.IsBodyHtml = False
    Mensagem.Priority = MailPriority.High

    Email.Send(Mensagem)

End Sub
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network
         host="smtp.jnmoura.com.br"
         port="587"
         userName="midiassociais@jnmoura.com.br"
         password="password"
         enableSsl="false"
    />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que estava errado e o que mudou no código do cara...

Comment: Primeiramente limpei o excesso de código (não utilizado). Praticamente alterei o enableSsl de true para false no web.config e deixei um e-mail fixo no Mensagem.From do Default.aspx.vb